# Android Studio Copying Projects

Tags: android-studio

Hi I wrote a project on Android Studio, now I just want to create a exact duplicate to it so I could try some experiments on the new copy without ruining the old version.How can I do that?

Someone told me just to copy the file in finder(I'm using mac). I did that, and managed to open the new version as project. But it is not working.I am sure I need to edit a few places as the file name has changed, but I don't know where are the places to edit, any idea?

Thanks !

Comment: Instead of copying file and wasting memory , better use git to manage different versions of project

Comment: Create a new git branch in your project and make changes. At any time you can change your branch or rollback changes if you have made any commits

Comment: You also don't need to "copy back" your changes when  using Git. You just merge in whatever extra lines of code you changed. Not entire files

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends on your project. Is it a small one or a big one with huge memory?

If it's a small one and you have enough memory in your Mac, just copy the whole folder instead of a file and paste it somewhere else. Then you can do anything you want to in the new one.

If your project is huge and don't want to waste memory, I suggest you to use `GitHub`.

Comment: No need of remote storage , it can be achieved locally using GIT

Comment: Note: Github isn't needed to play around with code features. A bare local repository works for all sizes of code

Answer (score 1):

Just Follow this steps:

1. Clean renamedProject
2. Go to java folder and Refactor > Rename to renamedProject
3. Change app name in strings.xml
4. Change applicationID to renamedProject if not already changed.
5. Sync Project

Check out Detailed Steps in Official Book:

https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-practicals/content/en/appendix_utilities.html#copy_project

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you can simply locate project folder in finder, and copy it at different location with new folder name. Now open it in Android studio. This would create a replica of your project.

But better approach to achieve your requirement is `GIT`. You can refer following [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/user-manual.html) for better git understanding.

Comment: It sounds good, but I am new to IT and coding.
I am using mac, can I still do that?

Comment: it's a must known skill in IT, you will improve it with practice. GIT can be implemented on any platform. Cheers